# IDLs explorers - Curiosity

Tags: idl, anchor-program-idl

Why do some idls ain't showing in solana.explorer and only showing on solscan?

Context:(Some programs had all idls deployed)
Was upgrading the idls on chain, noted that some programs on solana.explorer weren't showing anymore. Was wondering wtf did i do, till i checked Solscan and they were there.

exmple of one of the programs(devnet): propm845StqEBV57ZSnTe8EW8duzAxo5p7h4inhibXV

Answer (score 4):

I've taken a look and this is an Explorer bug: https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/issues/316 Sorry about that!

There's an error being caught when we try to parse your IDL: "Tuple enum variants not yet implemented."

I suspect the issue is the field `"Bounty" ["publicKey","u64"]` in your `proposalType` enum

The fix is probably to upgrade the Anchor SDK on Explorer, I'm pretty sure the error is caused by us using an older version without support for the type of enum you're using.

Comment: forgot to add that this idls were generated by the new idl build feature. But yes pretty sure has to do with older versions. thanks anyways.